# Adding 2 std_logic_vector in variable type VHDL

Tags: variables, logic, vhdl, addition

I'm working in this school project.
I have two std_logic_vector (31 downto 0) A and B, and I have a variable type std_logic_vector (32 downto 0) and I want to add A+B and put the result in my std_logic_vector with 32 bits.

This is my design:

```
library IEEE;    
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;    
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;    
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity Ej3 is
    Port ( A :     in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);   
           B :     in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);    
           S :     out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);    
           AluOp : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);    
           COut :  out STD_LOGIC;   
           Z :     out STD_LOGIC;    
           OFL :   out STD_LOGIC);    
end Ej3;


architecture Behavioral of Ej3 is

    begin

    process(AluOp)    
        variable Temp: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (32 downto 0);   
    begin

        Temp := A+B;
```

And I have this error: **found '0' definitions of operator "+", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "+"**

Can someone help??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you've included the standard library `numeric_std` and the nonstandard library `std_logic_arith` together. They conflict with each other so get rid of `std_logic_arith`.

Both of those packages implement arithmetic using the `unsigned` and `signed` types. It is strongly recommend that you use these types if you want to do arithmetic on vectors. It makes it explicitly clear that you want them interpreted in a numeric context. There is no "+" operator defined for the `std_logic_vector` type implemented in `std_logic_1164` which is why you get an error. You can augment that type with arithmetic operators in VHDL-2008 by also including `numeric_std_unsigned`. Again, it is better to just use the traditional `unsigned` type:

```
A : in unsigned(31 downto 0);
B : in unsigned(31 downto 0);

...

process(AluOp)
  variable temp : unsigned(32 downto 0);
begin

  temp := resize(A, temp'length) + B;
```

The length of the left and right sides of the assignment have to match so first resize the A signal, expanding it to 33 bits before adding the 32-bit signal B.

Comment: Consider still declaring the ports as `A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);` etc. for easy interface with other modules, and then convert `A` and `B` to `unsigned` in the expression like `resize(unsigned(A), temp'length) + unsigned(B)`.  If `temp` is also `std_logic_vector` then convert back after the addition using `std_logic_vector(resize...)`.

Comment: @Morten Zilmer I don't agree with the practice of converting back to less specific types unless necessary. The type system becomes painful to use and people then just avoid it. It's better to decide on the appropriate type and maintain it through as much hierarchy as possible. Anyone who's used Ada knows that it is impossible to get anything done without invoking lots of types. Using that same philosophy in VHDL makes it work for you rather than against. Keeping SLV ports has a place at the top level when you want to be able to swap a synthesized netlist with SLV ports into a testbench.

Comment: That closely related array types (bags of bits with the same base element types) only vary by type is because it's inconvenient to use attributes to distinguish functionality of operator functions. Verilog uses the equivalent of a subtype attribute to signify signed behavior. Instead VHDL replicates operators for each distinct type.  If there were a reason to prevent type conversion element base types would be unrelated - it's difficult to accidentally type convert. Avoiding doing so is merely coding style or convention without support in the standard.

Comment: @Kevin Thibedeau: Thanks for you comment, and it made me check some of my recent code.  This has an object that is initialized using `signed` to make a negative offset in 2's complement, then additions are made using `unsigned` since resulting value can be represented without a sign bit, and then finally the value is compared with some extraction from a `std_logic_vector`.  So the applied type of the object depends on the use in either initialize, add, or compare.  So in this case, I think it is hard to say, if any type is more native than the another.